# dojo parser and a TypeError using ArcGIS JS API

Tags: javascript, parsing, dojo, arcgis

I'm getting this error:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'parser.parse()')

Here's my code.

```
<script> 
    require([
      "esri/map", 
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", 
      "esri/dijit/Legend",
      "esri/digit/HomeButton",
      "dojo/_base/array", 
      "dojo/parser",
      "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", 
      "dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
      "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer", 
      "dojo/domReady!"
], function(
  Map, FeatureLayer, Legend, arrayUtils, parser, HomeButton
) {
    parser.parse();

    var map = new Map("map", {
        basemap: "streets",
        center: [-87.702733, 41.998508],
        zoom: 15
    });

    var home = new HomeButton ({
        map: map
    }, "HomeButton");
    home.startup();

  var circuits = new FeatureLayer("http://54.243.188.50:6080/arcgis/rest/services/TYLIN/Streetlights_Pilot/MapServer/6", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields:["*"]
  });

  var power = new FeatureLayer("http://54.243.188.50:6080/arcgis/rest/services/TYLIN/Streetlights_Pilot/MapServer/2", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    outFields:["*"]
  });


  //add the legend
  map.on("layers-add-result", function (evt) {
    var layerInfo = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function (layer, index) {
      return {layer:layer.layer, title:layer.layer.name};
    });
    if (layerInfo.length > 0) {
      var legendDijit = new Legend({
        map: map,
        layerInfos: layerInfo
      }, "legendDiv");
      legendDijit.startup();
    }
  });

  map.addLayers([circuits, power]);
});

</script>
```

I've been able to get this to run by splitting out the HomeButton part separate from the Legend part.  In the comer, I have to call dojo.parser.parse() -- but that doesn't work with the Legend part.

I don't really understand how the dojo/parser works so it's difficult for me to understand why some parts require dojo.parser.parse() and others require parser.parse().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a problem in your `require()`. `dojo/parser` is the 6th module you import, **however**, the parameter named `parser` is on the 5th place, so they don't match. The order of the modules you import **must** be the same as the parameters you use them in, so this is the correct way:

```js
require([
      "esri/map", 
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", 
      "esri/dijit/Legend",
      "esri/digit/HomeButton",
      "dojo/_base/array", 
      "dojo/parser",
      "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", 
      "dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
      "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer", 
      "dojo/domReady!"
], function(
  Map, FeatureLayer, Legend, HomeButton, arrayUtils, parser
) {
```

As you see, I switched HomeButton to another place and now the modules match the parameters.

- `esri/map` (1st module): `Map` (1st variable in function)
- `esri/layers/FeatureLayer` (2nd module): `FeatureLayer` (2nd parameter)
- `esri/dijit/Legend` (3rd module): `Legend` (3rd parameter)
- `esri/dijit/HomeButton` (4th module): `HomeButton` (4th parameter)
- `dojo/_base/array` (5th module): `arrayUtils` (5th parameter)
- `dojo/parser` (6th module): `parser` (6th parameter)

The reason why your code works if you seperate them is because you probably fix your `require()`. The reason why `dojo.parser.parse()` works is because it's old deprecated legacy code which doesn't use the parameter of the `require` callback.