# Having HomeButton and Overview together on ArcGIS Sever JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-js-api

Using ArcGIS Server JavaScript Api I am having issue on having Home Button and Map Overview on the map. For whatever reason the home button is not showing up the map. Here is the script:

```
<script>
  require([
    "esri/map", 
    "esri/dijit/OverviewMap", "dojo/parser","dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "esri/dijit/HomeButton", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/domReady!"
  ], function(
      Map, OverviewMap,
  parser, HomeButton, FeatureLayer       
     ) {
    parser.parse(); 
    var map = new Map("mapDiv", {
      basemap: "topo",
      center: [-126.416, 55.781],
      zoom: 6
    });
  //===================================================== Overview
    var overviewMapDijit = new OverviewMap({
      map: map,
      visible: true
    });
    overviewMapDijit.startup();

 //===================================================== Shapefile
    //add a layer to the map
    var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://somewhere/1", {
      mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    });
 map.addLayer(featureLayer);

 //===================================================== Home Button
var home = new HomeButton({
map: map
}, "HomeButton");
 home.startup();

  });
 </script>
```

and CSS for Home Button is:

```
#HomeButton { position: absolute;  top: 120px; left: 50px;  z-index: 2; }
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

From your what I can see is that your **"esri/dijit/HomeButton" module** is loaded at 6th position whereas while writing the `function(Map, OverviewMap, parser, HomeButton, FeatureLayer)` you have mentioned the HomeButton parameter at the 4th position.

**If your put your module also at the 4th position**

```
require([
    "esri/map", 
    "esri/dijit/OverviewMap", "dojo/parser", "esri/dijit/HomeButton", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/domReady!"
  ]
```

***and likewise all the parameters of the function at the correct position, then everything should go well***

Also for your reference on the same issue you can take a look at this [how to correctly place import modules and corresponding parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305924/dojo-parser-and-a-typeerror-using-arcgis-js-api) link